# How to get specific string value using REGEX in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string content.

```
$string = "FIRST he ate some lettuces and some French beans, and then he ate some radishes AND then, feeling rather sick, he went to look for some parsley.";
```

Here I want to take a specific string

```
"then he ate some radishes"
```

How can I do it with REGEX? I want it in REGEX only

```
I want to pass just 2 parameters like 
1. then 
2. radishes
```

so finally I want output like `"then he ate some radishes"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`/(?<=then).*(?=radishes)/`](https://regex101.com/r/sVrOc0/2) to get everything between `then` and `radishes`.

```
$re = '/(?<=then).*(?=radishes)/';
$str = 'FIRST he ate some lettuces and some French beans, and then he ate some radishes AND then, feeling rather sick, he went to look for some parsley.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Break down:

- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=then)`: Assert that the Regex below matches
  then matches the characters then literally (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Positive Lookahead `(?=radishes)`: Assert that the Regex below matches
  radishes matches the characters radishes literally (case sensitive)

The requirement in OP is to match everything including `then` and `radishes`, so you can use `/then.*radishes/` in place of `/(?<=then).*(?=radishes)/`

To make the regex non greedy, you should go for `/then.*?radishes/` and `/(?<=then).*?(?=radishes)/`

Comment: Note that the desired output is "then he ate some radishes", so the lookahead and lookbehind are unnecessary.

Comment: You can use `/then.*radishes/` to match everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use this

```
$string = "FIRST he ate some lettuces and some French beans, and then he ate some radishes AND then, feeling rather sick, he went to look for some parsley.";

preg_match("/then(.*?)radishes/", $string, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

You can practice in https://regexr.com/

My demo see here https://regexr.com/3mj4v